# How to change style of an element based on window width in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, vue-component

I am trying to change the styling on an HTML element when the window size is smaller than 500px. Currently I have a computed property that defines a background-image for the element. I've tried using an if statement inside the computed property to check whether window.innerWidth < 500, but it seems like I can't do logic inside computed properties. My latest attempt was to create a method that checks the window width and if it is less than 500, it reasigns the computed property with the updated value. However, this does not seem to work.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```js
<template>
  <div class="hero" :style="bgImage">
</template
```

```js
data() {
    return {
      window: {
        width: 0
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
    this.handleResize()
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
  },
  methods: {
    handleResize() {
      if (window.width < 500) {
        this.bgImage = `backgroundImage: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(245, 246, 252, 0) 45%,rgb(0, 0, 0) 100%), url(${this.hero.image})`
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    bgImage() {
      return {
        backgroundImage: `url(${this.hero.image})`
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can do logic in computed properties but they are only reactive to changes on things Vue controls which does not include `window`

Comment: In order to use your `handleResize` method, `bgImage` should be a `data` property, not computed. `hero.image` should also be defined somewhere

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use plain old CSS media queries to handle this?

Comment: @Phil I am passing data from hero in as a prop. I would use regular CSS media queries, but I since I am looping through images, I need to have a dynamic way to access changing images.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `computed` to check your `width` data changes.

I changed your code this way

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      window: {
        width: 0,
      },
    },
    computed: {
      bgImage() {
        if (this.width < 500) {
          return {
            backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(245, 246, 252, 0) 45%,rgb(0, 0, 0) 100%), url(${this.hero.image})`
          }
        } else {
          return {
            backgroundImage: `url(${this.hero.image})`
          }
        }
      }
    }

    created: function() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
      },
      destroyed: function() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
      },
      methods: {
        handleResize() {
          this.width = window.innerWidth;
        }
      },
  };
```